# Using one data frame as a mask for extracting data from another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and I'm struggling with a data formation issue. I'm attempting to extract a set of values from a data frame by using a separate data frame as the criteria for my selection.

As an example, here is my original data:

```
Raw Data:

1 A  B  C  D  E  F
2 25 52 33 92 83 14
3 23 31 13 13 53 34
4 13 53 23 89 35 93
5 89 90 91 91 90 89
```

I'm trying to use a data frame of the same size similar to the following to "filter" that data:

```
Data Frame "mask":

1 08 09 10 08 09 10
2  1  2  3  4  1  2
3  1  2  3  4  1  2
4  2  3  4  1  2  3
5  2  3  4  1  2  3
```

For this example, I would like to form a vector from values in the raw data whos corresponding value in the data frame "mask" is equal to 1 and when the first row in the mask is equal to 8. In this case the result would be:

```
res = c(25, 23, 89, 91)
```

As I said, I'm relatively new to R and I have found that the simplest questions tend to be the most difficult to find answers for since most people don't have to ask them.. So hopefully this is a simple problem. =)

If this has been discussed elsewhere, a link would be very helpful. Otherwise any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `RDat` and `mask` are the datasets

```
 RDat[rep(colnames(mask)=="08",each=nrow(mask)) & (mask==1)]
 #[1] 25 23 89 91
```

#### Update

This would be a bit more compact

```
RDat[colnames(mask)[col(mask)]=="08" & mask==1]
#[1] 25 23 89 91
```

Comment: This works beautifully! I knew there was a much more elegant way to do this than loops. Thanks!